# How can I detect app crash

Tags: android

I have an application. If it crashed because of not responding, low memory etc. How can I detect crash and its reason. So that I can send these data to server next time the app starts. I don't want activity manger solution because it's not working as expected.

Comment: [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/)?

Comment: I have seen it before. But it is not free. Any other solutions

Comment: since when it is not free?

Comment: try ACRA: https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/). It is part of twitter [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/android?locale=en-us), a mobile platform which is

> made of three modular kits that address some of the most common and
>   pervasive challenges that all app developers face: stability,
>   distribution, revenue and identity. It combines the services of
>   Crashlytics, MoPub, Twitter.

You can read more [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/introducing-fabric) about it. Crashlytics should be free, or at least so claims their [pricing page](http://try.crashlytics.com/pricing/).

Comment: Stupid me. Thought it's not free seeing the pricing link there

Comment: no worries. good luck with it

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric. Crashlytics and Fabric are completely free for all developers.